Why Hibernate not saving new child object in OneToMany relation
I'm learning Hibernate ( v. 6.6.1 final) and have a problem

I have two entity classes

Person
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "java_seq_generator_person"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "java_seq_generator_person",
            sequenceName = "person_id_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name",nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Item> items;
    
    // save item method
    public void saveItem(Item item) {
        if (this.items == null) {
            this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        item.setOwner(this);
        this.items.add(item);
    }
    // constructors, getters and setters
}

Item
@Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "java_seq_generator_item"
    )
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "java_seq_generator_item",
            sequenceName = "item_id_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person owner;

    @Column(name = "item_name", nullable = false)
    private String itemName;

    // constructors, getters and setters
    ...
}


one record in table Person
{ id: 13,
name: "Test Person",
age: 77 }

Then i get this person from database -> create new item -> and add this item to my person, but hibernate generate only SELECT sql query for get person from db, and no INSERT query for child item;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config
                .addAnnotatedClass(Person.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Item.class);

        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();

            Person person = session.get(Person.class, 13);

            Item item = new Item("Test item");
            person.saveItem(item);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }
}

I don't understand why, cause when i get object(person) from db (Persistent/Managed state), and set CascadeType for child; i think Hibernate will automatic save my child item, cause object person change;
so my question is why my child item is not saving and how properly configure that to save child item when parent is changed ?

try CascadeType.ALL instead of CascadeType.PERSIST, it works but CascadeType.ALL seems redundant to me
try call session.persist() but my object already in Managed state
Should i manually save item? i think if i set cascade, hibernate will automatically save my child


Are you getting an error?

No error,  my child item not inserted in database, when i add it to my parent person List, and i don't understand why :(
i found some solutions but i think they are wrong

Can you show the entire code of the service where you save Person?

update post, i use only two entities and main function where i test this relation in Hibernate

Your code doesn't look like it should work. For example, factory.getCurrentSession() should throw an exception if the session isn't open.

this code works without exception because of
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread in my hibernate.properties

So in my opinion the problem is that CascadeType.PERSIST applies when the parent entity is newly created and explicitly persisted. Since person was retrieved (not newly created) CascadeType.PERSIST is ignored.
Proper CascadeType in this case is MERGE (it will cascade changes to associated entities even when the parent entity is already managed).
CascadeType.ALL works because it includes CascadeType.MERGE.
